# Mercurial : "diff" of a changeset in template

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to display the diff of each changed file in a changeset, using a template.

What I need is something very similar to "hg diff" command.  I cannot find anything which might serve my purpose in the help [here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates)

To add context, I am trying to use this template in Bugzilla extension. I need to add the diff of the changes which went in to bugzilla ticket.

Comment: 1. Describe your business-task in easy words, without any assumptions, that you want, something like "I want in log command output also diffs of touched in changeset files" 2. Template is wrong choice, it may be styles 3. Read about aliases and, specially, about shell-aliases in Mercurial

Comment: Well, I need to add a comment to bugzilla ticket on check in of changes to mercurial. I am using Bugzilla extension to do this.  And, I need the comment to have the diff of changes which went in.

Comment: OK, read http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension and note `style` parameter. Read about styling in Mercurial and if you'll be able write style for standalone `hg log --style`(not sure is it possible), you can re-use style in extension

Comment: A style is basically a collection of templates and its possible to write standalone style files. But I still can't find a template variable which could print out the file diffs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use diff() pattern

(extract from `hg help templates` - better than URL referenced by you)

```
- diff([includepattern [, excludepattern]])
```

You if you don't specify any patterns, it will simply give you the equivalent of `hg log -p`. If you want to print diff *per file*, you will need to pass **explicit** filenames as `includepattern` parameter, like

`hg log -r tip --template "{diff('mercurial/bundlerepo.py')}"`

Looping through the list of files (like `"{files % '{file}'}"` in templates help) seems broken in this case (well, I didn't manage to make it work). Probably it's a bug, so you can write to mercurial discussion list to get confirmation.

Anyways, to get more luxury support, better to write to mercurial discussion list, or join #mercurial IRC and ask :)

Also they will guide you on how to achieve what you are trying to do in better way - seems you are trying to reinvent something